# How can I make player movement relative to the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity box physics-based game, for that I'm pushing the box. I want the player to be able to move the camera on the X-Axis around the box, but that means if the player moves the camera to the back of the box the movement reverses.

I have tried looking at other posts/tutorials but none do what I'm trying to do.

Here's my player movement code,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardBackForce = 1000f;
    public float leftRightForce = 1000f;

    // Gets component Rigidbody
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Used for movement
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardBackForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, -forwardBackForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-leftRightForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb.AddForce(leftRightForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my camera movement code,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerCamera : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform PlayerTransform;

    private Vector3 _cameraOffset;

    [Range(0.01f, 1.0f)]
    public float SmoothFactor = 0.05f;

    public bool LookAtPlayer = false;

    public bool RotateAroundPlayer = true;

    public float RotationSpeed = 5.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _cameraOffset = transform.position - PlayerTransform.position;
    }

    // LateUpdate is called after Update
    void LateUpdate()
    {

        if(RotateAroundPlayer)
        {
            Quaternion camTurnX = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotationSpeed, Vector3.up);
            _cameraOffset = camTurnX * _cameraOffset;

        }


        Vector3 newPos = PlayerTransform.position + _cameraOffset;

        transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, newPos, SmoothFactor);

        if (LookAtPlayer || RotateAroundPlayer)
            transform.LookAt(PlayerTransform);
    }




}
```

All I need is a way to make player movement relative to the camera.

One final note is I'm working on a collision system so the box can't keep pushing on the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are using only the global `Z` or `X` direction.

I guess what you rather wanted is a direction in the Camera looking direction so use e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;
}

...

rb.AddForce(mainCamera.transform.forward * forwardBackForce * Time.deltaTime);

...

rb.AddForce(mainCamera.transform.right * -leftRightForce * Time.deltaTime);
```